# #ZipLib error while decompressing GZip

Tags: gzip, sharpziplib, compression

I'm getting this error while trying to decompress some GZ files with #ZipLib 0.85.5

Those file are not corrupted, I'm able to decompress it correctly using 7-Zip.

ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.SharpZipBaseException Unexpected EOF

Comment: Post the code you are using to help us come up with your error...

Answer (score 0):

You could try a different managed library?  I don't know much about sharpziplib, but why wouldn't you just use the built-in [System.IO.Compression.GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) to unpack .gz data ?